# Calculating Fold Lines Based on Paper Thicknesses?

Tags: paper

I am wanting to know how do you calculate the curvature distance a fold line may produce based on paper thickness?

For instance I am wanting to do artwork on a thick paper stock and I want to make sure my artwork is within the folds instead of perhaps very close to it. As what I am doing is on small thick boxes, it is critical that I can work this out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Length of a perfect circular fold for 180 degree turn is **π × W**:

[image: corner fold]

**Image 1** Corner shift

In practice thus you have some slack to the inner side, so W is actually width of paper plus how much inner radius you use. So W is somewhere between 1-2 times the width of the card stock. and the amount of paper that the corner eats is:

**π × 1-2 × w × a/180**

where a is the angle of your corner, and w is the width of your cardstock. A value 2 might be pushing it i have never needed to measure card stock this accurately so i allays used a value of 1, but i do regularly accurate sheet metal work which is similar tech. So this is the theoretical underpinning.

Ultimately: Ask your printer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I am a bit confused.

What it 'TT' symbol? 

And what is 'a', this is the radius of the angle?

Could you give me an example and your calculation so I can see how you calculate it so I can replicate it as its easier to see it in example since geometry is not my strongsuit since I finished it at school 20 years ago :(

Thanks again.

Comment: It's not "TT" it's a π symbol which = [Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)

Comment: @Ninjab the "TT" is the greek letter pi which is a mathematical constant. a is the angle of your fold if you have a full fold it would br 180 degrees if its the side of a box it would most likely be 90. w is the width of your cardstock

Comment: Heh yeh I realied after I posted it cause I recognised pi with the curves. Thanks.

However how do I work out this calculation. For instance could you show me an example you would use to work it out. I am not that mathematically gifted. Thanks.

Comment: @Ninjab NP, assume you want to fold a 90 degree turn then you would calculate 3.14159*1.1* Width of card*90/180 this is the amount of paper you loose in the fold. Im allowing for not a operfect fold hece 1.1 .

Comment: Ah now I got it, thanks a lot.

This will also be helpful when I need to put a box over another box so I can work out the outer size based on paper thickness.

Comment: @joojaa so lets say I have 0.35mm thickness of paper, I would go:

Pie x 1.1 x 0.35 x 90/180 = 0.60mm ? And if I had 4 corners to wrap around a box I would be losing 0.60 x 4 (2.4mm) of extra material I would need?

Comment: @Ninjab yes something along those lines yes thought a bend is usually closer to 2. 1.1 is a very sharp corner Also you will have alignment issues to take into consideration